# JupyterLab: How to save a figure from the notebook

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying the new JupyterLab and am having trouble saving figures. Using vanilla Jupyter notebooks, I can two-fingers click (using macOS, Safari or Chrome) and I get a browser menu that allows me to copy or save the figure.

In JupyterLab, this menu is replaced by notebook specific one with cell-related functions, as seen here:

[image]

Is there a way I can save a figure directly from the notebook in JupyterLab?

Comment: Please open an issue on the JupyterLab tracker. JupyterLab is not yet in Beta, so interface and functionality are still changing.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @Matt, I opened an issue in GitHub and got the answer: the old menu is available by holding down Shift while doing a two-fingers click on a Mac, or doing a Shift + right-click on Linux/windows

Source: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3043#event-1272299457

Answer (score 21):

`Shift + Right click` works well (as foglerit mentioned).

Another alternative is to right on the output of a cell and select `Create New View for Output`. This will allow you to interact with all figures from an output as if they were just images.

Comment: Thanks (+1) for your answer. However, it does not work always. For example, in case of Sankey Graph.